# Invalid association. Make sure that accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for :mark_images association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The error refers to

> **f.link_to_add**

... line. When I remove that line, it works fine. But then I can't add more images.

```
<%= nested_form_for(:mark, url: place_mark_path, validate: true, html: {multipart: true}, 'data-update-target' => 'marks', class: 'marks') do |f| %>

  ...

  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.check_box :mark %>

  <%= f.fields_for :mark_images do |p| %>
    <%= p.file_field :image %>
    <%= p.link_to_remove %><br>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.link_to_add "+ Add another image", :mark_images %>   <------ Problem

  <%= f.submit " Submit" %>

<% end %>
```

routes

```
  resources :places do
    resources :marks
  end
```

marks_controller

```
def new
    query = @factual.table('places')
    @place = query.filters('factual_id' => params[:place_id]).first
    @mark = Mark.new
    @mark.mark_images.build
end
```

mark model

```
  has_many :mark_images, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :mark_images
```

mark_images model

```
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

Comment: Post your full `nested_form_for` code.

Comment: :attachable doesn't work either.

Comment: Changing it to `<%= f.link_to_add "+ Add another image", :mark %>` may work.

Comment: can you post a sample app on github which reproduces this issue?

Comment: OR Put it inside `fields_for` as `<%= p.link_to_add "+ Add another image", :mark_images %>` will work

Comment: And finally,if those two didn't work,change your first param of your `nested_form_for` as `@mark`.

Comment: It seems to be working. Answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: Tell me Which one worked,so that i cab post it as an answer.

Comment: Ok,I will be posting it as an answer ASAP :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing this line

```
<%= nested_form_for(:mark, url: place_mark_path, validate: true, html: {multipart: true}, 'data-update-target' => 'marks', class: 'marks') do |f| %>
```

to this should work

```
<%= nested_form_for(@mark, url: place_mark_path, validate: true, html: {multipart: true}, 'data-update-target' => 'marks', class: 'marks') do |f| %>
```