# Rails "Invalid association" error with nested_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested form, using the 'nested_form' gem on Rails 4.2.5, and
am encountering the error:

`Invalid association. Make sure that accepts_nested_attributes_for
is used for :monthly_charges association.`

I've looked at these posts:

[Invalid association. Make sure that accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for :mark_images association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462183/invalid-association-make-sure-that-accepts-nested-attributes-for-is-used-for-m)
[Invalid association. Make sure that accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for :questions association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626186/invalid-association-make-sure-that-accepts-nested-attributes-for-is-used-for-q)
[Rails nested_form Invalid association. Make sure that accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for assoctiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868249/rails-nested-form-invalid-association-make-sure-that-accepts-nested-attributes)

... and I don't see what I'm doing wrong, based on the answers.

As far as I can tell, I have the right association set up in my model:

`class Lease < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :monthly_charges
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :monthly_charges, allow_destroy: true
end`

... and I've declared the `monthly_charges_attributes` fields in
`lease_params` in the controller:

`def lease_params
    params.require(:lease).permit(
        :begin_date, :end_date, :renewal_date, 
        :move_out_date, :rent, :deposit_required, :late_day,
        :late_fee, :extra_day_late_fee,
        monthly_charges_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy]
    )
end`

And in the view, I have:

`<p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a monthly charge", :monthly_charges %></p>`

I have no idea why this should not work.

UPDATE: The `MonthlyCharge` model is currently:

`class MonthlyCharge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lease
end`

Comment: could you please add to the question the `MonthlyCharge` model

Comment: @neydroid, thanks for looking. I've added it here. I've tried a couple of different things, including having just an empty shell of a class for MonthlyCharge, but here's how it stands currently.

Comment: could you add the view that you're rendering using this gem? so far I don't see any error :(

Comment: @neydroid, I think I've figured it out. I'm using a nested association (thus the need for `nested_form`), and the  form is trying to find an association with the wrong model. Chalk that up to my inexperience and a non-specific error message (although I might have found it digging through the stack trace; instead I tried to use `coccoon`, whose error message *did* give me the right class).